# change object if exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm filling an array with objects.
I want to check if object with certain `id` already exists.

If object exists then replace `value` in the object.

For example:

```
function art(id,value)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.value=value;
}
```

An array `var my_array=[];`

Adding to an array `my_array.push(art);`

How to check if object already exists and then replace it with the new value.

Comment: take a look if jQuery [inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function can solve your problem

Comment: @user123_456 if any of the below answers solve you problem it might be worth marking it as your answer, it could help others in the future :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use key pair type associative array then you don't even need to check that it exists because:

1. if it doesnt exist it will be created.
2. if it does exist it will be overwritten.

example:

```
var my_array = new Array();

function art(id,value)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.value=value;
}   

var myArt = new art(1,'value');    

//if an array item with this id exists it will be overidden else a new
//array item will be created
my_array[myArt.id] = myArt;
```

**UPDATED FOR CLARITY**

Comment: what if I don't want to create the k/v-pair if the key does not exist, and instead simply ignore it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this :-

```
for (var i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++) {
    if(my_array[i].id=="SOMEID")
        my_array[i].value="NEWValue";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are looking for, but if you want to check object for particular id and replace its value than I think

```
    for(var i = 0; i < my_array.length; i++){
      if(my_array[i].id === "#123"){
         my_array[i].value = "Some New Value to it"
      }
    }
```

PS : always check with === try to avoid ==, as == has unexpected behavior

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) for that:

```
var my_array = {};

function art(id, value)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.value = value;
}

// test 1:
var newArt1 = new art(1, "value");
if(typeof my_array[newArt1.id] === "undefined" ){  // check if id 1 exists in object;
    my_array[newArt1.id] = newArt1.value;
}

// test 2:
var newArt2 = new art("xxx", "value");
if(typeof my_array[newArt2.id] === "undefined" ){  // check if id xxx exists in object;
    my_array[newArt2.id] = newArt2.value;
}
```

Comment: when checking for a property/key in an object you don't need `typeof`, simply do `if (my_array[newArt1.id])`

Comment: @metadings That only works if the value is truthy. If the value is falsey (`undefined`, `null`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`), your idea doesn't work. The way to check for existence in an object is with `in` or `hasOwnProperty`. To check if it's not `undefined`, just use `!== undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below example:

```
    var my_array = [];

function art(id, value) {
    this.id = id;
    this.value = value;
}

function checkIfExistsAndReplace(inArr, object, newValue) {
    for (i = 0; i < inArr.length; i++) {
        if (inArr[i].id == object.id && inArr[i].value == object.value) {
            inArr[i].value = newValue;
            return inArr;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    my_array.push(new art("name", i));
}

console.log(my_array);

console.log(checkIfExistsAndReplace(my_array, new art('name', 4), 'NEWVALUE'));

console.log(checkIfExistsAndReplace(my_array, new art('name', 5)));
```

Also see the fiddle below

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kakarikos/juanu/)